# JQuery <tr> tag with filter by attributes and get current index

Tags: jquery, html

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tr code="01"> <td><input type="text" name="A"/></td></tr>
    <tr code="02"> <td><input type="text" name="B"/></td></tr>
    <tr code="03"> <td><input type="text" name="C"/></td></tr>
    <tr code="01"> <td><input type="text" name="D"/> </td></tr>
    <tr code="01"> <td><input type="text" name="E"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

When E is inputed, I need to filter tr with code = "01" and get index of E (result is 2)

How to do this?

Comment: share what you have tried so far

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I need to check. If index = 0 -> do AAA, if index > 0 do BBB

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the parent `tr` using [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. Get the value of `code` using [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
3. Get the matching rows by getting the parent table and then the `tr` elements having the same `code` using the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).
4. Get the index using [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Example:

```js
$("input[type='text']").change(function() {

  var $parent = $(this).closest("tr");
  var code = $parent.attr("code");
  var $codeRows = $(this).closest("table").find("tr[code='" + code + "']");
  var index = $codeRows.index($parent);

  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr code="01">
    <td><input type="text" name="A" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr code="02">
    <td><input type="text" name="B" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr code="03">
    <td><input type="text" name="C" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr code="01">
    <td><input type="text" name="D" /> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr code="01">
    <td><input type="text" name="E" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to detect whether or not the `input` `tr` code is within the same tree or not:

```js
function check (val){
var el=$('tr').find("[name="+val+"]").parent().parent();
var code= el.attr("code");
  if(el.is( "[code~="+code+"]")){
    var elements=$('tr').filter(function(){
      return $(this).is( "[code~="+code+"]" );
    });
    console.log(elements.index(el)); 
  }
}


$("input[type='text']").on("input", function() {
  if($(this).val().length > 0){
   check(($(this).val())); 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr code="01"> <td><input type="text" name="A"/></td></tr>
    <tr code="02"> <td><input type="text" name="B"/></td></tr>
    <tr code="03"> <td><input type="text" name="C"/></td></tr>
    <tr code="01"> <td><input type="text" name="D"/> </td></tr>
    <tr code="01"> <td><input type="text" name="E"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Explanation:

```
function check (val){
var el=$('tr').find("[name="+val+"]").parent().parent();
var code= el.attr("code");
  if(el.is( "[code~="+code+"]")){
    var elements=$('tr').filter(function(){
      return $(this).is( "[code~="+code+"]" );
    });
    console.log(elements.index(el)); 
  }
}
```

is used to detect if the inputted value was in the same `code` attribute tree. If that's the case then filter all elements within that code and get the index.

```
$("input[type='text']").on("input", function() {
   if($(this).val().length > 0){
    check(($(this).val())); 
   }
});
```

is used to detect input on `input textbox`. If there are any input then it would fire the function above.

Related resources:

- [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/): Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.
- [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/): Get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. (Double mean parent of the parent (*Grandpa*))
- [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/): Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.
- [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/): Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements or set one or more attributes for every matched element.
- [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/): Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return *`true`* if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.
- [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/): Search for a given element from among the matched elements.